# Django приложение для хранения изображений к товару

Tags: django, django-orm

Какие готовые решения существуют для хранения картинок к товару к каталогу продукции.

Требуется или готовый минимальный пример реализации или приложение с минимальным функционалом, монстры вида oscar тут не нужны.

Разобранные варианты. Связь один к одному, json field, GenericRelation.

Недостатки:

json - нужно многое делать поверх

foreign key - большое количество запросов

GenericRelation - запросы, сложность в понимании кода.

Хотелось бы найти оптимальное решение, желательно готовое к подключению в проект.

---

Примечание

Предложенный @FeroxTL вариант решения через prefetch_related является как самым популярным, так и наиболее оптимальным по производительности. К тому же всегда есть возможность ускориться через избыточность копируя данные для вывода в дополнительное поле в таблице товара.

Дополнение ответа

1. [дополняет данный ответ, как добавить в админку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537593/multiple-images-per-model)
2. [сниппет сортировки, требует незначительной доработки для изображений](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1053/)
3. [готовое приложение из которого можно использовать участки кода, например сохранение изображения](https://github.com/mirumee/django-images)

Comment: Используйте `select_related()` и запросов больше не станет при использовании `ForeignKey`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классически данная проблема полностью решается средствами django без каких-либо дополнений. Получится одна модель для представления товара и одна модель для изображений, примерно так:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=200)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name='Товар', related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField('Изображение', upload_to='images')
```

Чтобы выбрать все товары вместе с их изображениями используйте [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
qs = Product.objects.all().prefetch_related('images')
```

Тогда в цикле вы сможете перебрать товары следующим образом:

```
for product in qs:
    print(qs.name)
    for image in product.images.all():  # дополнительных запросов не будет
        print('->', image.url)
```

Технически это будет реализовано как 2 запроса на любое количество результатов - первый запрос загружает товары, второй - картинки к загруженным товарам. Для программиста это происходит прозрачно, никаких телодвижений совершать не требуется.

Comment: от какой модели к какой идет связь, в примере нет данных об этом?

Comment: @Igor прошу прощения, у себя в редакторе изменил, а в ответ изменения скопировать забыл. Исправил ответ. Конечно же связь от ProductImage к Product должна быть

Comment: Ответ верный. Добавил информацию дополняющую данный ответ в вопрос, т.к. в комментариях будет не видно, править пока нет полного работающего кода не то.